# S3 file upload 'Expected params.Key to be a string'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to S3 with my NodeJS backend, but I can't get it to work.

This is the error I am getting:

```
InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Key to be a string
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575922+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.fail (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:50:37)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575923+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.validateType (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:232:10)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575923+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.validateString (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:154:32)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575923+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.validateScalar (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:130:21)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575924+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.validateMember (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:94:21)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575924+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.validateStructure (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:75:14)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575925+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.validateMember (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:88:21)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575925+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ParamValidator.validate (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/param_validator.js:34:10)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575925+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:132:42)
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575926+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Request.callListeners (/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20) {
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575926+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'InvalidParameterType',
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575927+00:00 app[web.1]:   time: 2021-07-25T15:07:10.571Z
2021-07-25T15:07:10.575927+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

This is my uploadFile() function:

```
const bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME;
const region = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION;
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY;

const s3 = new S3({
  region,
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey,
});


// uploads a file to s3
function uploadFile(file) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: file.filename,
    Body: fileStream,
  };

  return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise();
}
exports.uploadFile = uploadFile;
```

It gets the file using multer middleware which works just fine, I can see the file with console.log(). This is the controller:

```
const uploadAvatar = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.user;
    const file = req.file;
    const result = await uploadFile(file);
    await unlinkFile(file.path);
    await knex('users').where('id', id).update({
      avatar_url: result.Key,
    });

    return res.status(200).send({ msg: 'Photo has been uploaded.' });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message });
  }
};


//route
router.post('/upload-avatar', auth, upload.single('image'), customerController.uploadAvatar);
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong here, I tried to change the key to just "test" but without success. I also couldn't find a related issue anywhere.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Presumably it's the `s3.upload(...)` call that raises that exception. Did you double check the type and content in uploadParams.Key? What does that value look like?

Comment: @jarmod yes I checked them, the uploadParams.key is the filename that multer returns. Just a string of characters.

Comment: Well, it looks like the AWS SDK is telling you it isn't a string. I'd check that you have an up to date AWS SDK and [enable internal logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/logging-sdk-calls.html) to see if it helps you identify the root cause.

Comment: Can you try to add a simple string as the key name: ` Key: 'testingFilename'`, does it work or still throws an error?

Comment: That still throws the same error..